# Javascript method not toggling as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a word matching exercise game that is written in javascript and html. When the user clicks add more the `add_more()` method adds a new key, description pair to the keys and descriptions input boxes. Then when the user clicks generate html the `generate_html()` method should create a new textarea box with the html to be generated.

Expected:
The user clicks add more then clicks generate html new html is generated once.

Actual:
The user clicks add more then clicks generate html new html is generated more than once.

[image]

The program is relatively simple. These are the two methods

```
function generate_html() {
      // retrieve the keys and descriptions. Then load them into their respective arrays.
      const e_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='el']");
      const d_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dl']");
      let elArray = [];
      let dlArray = [];
      const title = document.getElementById('title_input').value;
      e_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) elArray.push(i.value) });
      d_inputs.forEach( i => { if(i.value) dlArray.push(i.value) });

      //have we added more?
      if(addMore && htmlGenerated){
        // then delete the old textarea.
        textarea = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
        textarea.remove();
        // delete the controls.
        controls = document.getElementById("program1");
        controls.remove();
      }

    
      //has the html already been generated? 
      if(!htmlGenerated){
        //fetch the results box
        results = document.getElementById("results");
        
        //create textarea
        textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("id","generated_html_textarea");
        
        // initialize blank html
        let html = '';
        html += '<div id=\"maincontentstyle\">\n'
        html += '\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t<div id=\"boxstyle\">\n'
        html += '\t\t\t<h3 id=\"title\">'+title+"</h3>\n";

        //create key inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<div class="source">\n' 
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id="s';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">\n';
          html += `\t\t\t\t\t\t\t${elArray[i-numberOfInputs]}\n`;
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
  
        //create description inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<table id=\"tablestyle\">\n'
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n'
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id="row';
          id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
          html += id;
          html +='">\n';
          html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html += id;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\">'
          html +='</div>\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n'
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\"d'
          html += id
          html += '\">\n'
          html +=`\t\t\t\t\t\t\t${dlArray[i-numberOfInputs]}\n`;
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n' 
          html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
        html += '\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t</center>\n'
        html += '</div>'

        // html generation is done.
        htmlGenerated = true;
        textarea.value = html;
        results.appendChild(textarea);

        // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
        controls = document.createElement("div");
        controls.setAttribute("id","program1");
        controls.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span>';
        results.appendChild(controls);
      }
    }
```

```
 function add_more() {
      // we've added more inputs.
      addMore = true;

      // set html generated to false, because new inputs have been added.
      htmlGenerated = false;
      
      // increment the number of inputs.
      numberOfInputs++;

      //fetch the input boxes.
      inputs = document.getElementById("inputBoxes");
      
      //create a new row for a key term.
      row = document.createElement("div");
      row.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the key term text.
      row.innerHTML = "Key Term ";
      row.innerHTML +=numberOfInputs;
      row.innerHTML +=" :";

      // create the input for the key.
      key = document.createElement("input");
      key.setAttribute("id","el"+numberOfInputs);

      //add the key to the row.
      row.appendChild(key);

      //create a row for the new description.
      row2 = document.createElement("div");
      row2.setAttribute("class","row");

      // set the description text.
      row2.innerHTML = "Description  "
      row2.innerHTML+=numberOfInputs;
      row2.innerHTML+=" :";

      // create the description input
      description = document.createElement("input");
      description.setAttribute("id","dl"+numberOfInputs);

      // add the description to the row.
      row2.appendChild(description);

      // add the rows for the key and the description to the inputBoxes.
      inputs.appendChild(row);
      inputs.appendChild(row2);
    }
```

the gitub link is [here](https://github.com/EvanGertis/Selected-Topics/blob/main/wordMatch/Section5_3.html).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: That's why I added the github because it can be copy and pasted.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @EvanGertis how you reviewed the fix in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are **appending** child nodes to the result:

```
211  results.appendChild = textarea;
```

Change this to use [replaceChildren](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) so you rather replace the content and not keep appending:

```
211  results.replaceChildren(textarea);
```